# Navigating around instantiating an abstract class, is there a flaw of in my OOP design?

Tags: java, oop, generics, interface, abstract-class

After reading a number of questions regarding abstract classes and interfaces, I am still unsure about how I should go about designing my code, so at the risk of having missed a possible duplicate, here's my situation.

I am working on a number of utility classes that are meant to handle a nasty hierarchy of a particular type of object. While the precise details of the object is irrelevant, it should suffice to say that it's not a general solution whatsoever. So I started by writing a `CustomNode` and a `CustomHierarchy` class.

A bit later on I realized that it's much smarter to produce a more general solution, which can be reused in different context and easily tested without having to create lots of mock instances of the aforementioned complicated class. I could easily provide all the common code in interfaces and abstract classes, and just provide the specific bits where they are needed! (this I believe is the whole point with OOP?)

So far I have:

- an interface `Relatable` which simply holds an enum of possible relations that nodes might have to one another, and a method signature of `getRelation(Relatable other)`
- an abstract class `Node<E>` which implements the `Relatable` and contains all utility methods (e.g. `addChild()` or `getNextSibling()`. The only method this class is missing is the `getRelation(Relatable other)`.
- a concrete class `Hierarchy<E>` which will define how to build up the hierarchy of the nodes, starting from a `Collection<E>` which holds the data.

The idea is to extend the `Node<E>` and `Hierarchy<E>` classes with appropriate subclasses based on the problem at hand. The first two are done without any major hustle but I am having problems with the `Hierarchy<E>` class since it has a *private* method `addNodeToHierarchy(E data)` which tries to instantiate a `Node<E>` and place it in the hierarchy. This obviously fails as the node class is abstract and can't be instantiated.

I understand why this is not working, but I am not sure how I should go about circumventing this problem. Is there a flaw in my design? Should I add a static `createNewNode(E data)` method in the `Node<E>` and use that instead? Another option I can think of is to detach the `Node` from getting the relation and go with a `Relator` interface instead. This can't be a unique problem by any chance, so what's "good practice" in this situation?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide who should know how a `Node<E>` must be constructed from from an instance of `E`. It could be the instance of `E`, it could be the `Node` class, it could be the Hierarchy, or it could be the caller of `addNodeToHierarchy()`.

If it's the caller of `addNodeToHierarchy()`, then either you make it take an instance of `Node<E>` instead of an instance of `E`, or you make it take an instance of some `NodeFactory<E>`, to which the method will delegate to transform the data into a node. This factory could also be passed as an argument to the hierarchy constructor if all the nodes are constructed by the same factory.

Comment: So far I have been considering `addNodeToHierarchy()` as a private method in the `Hierarchy` class, and it seems natural to me that the `Node` class is where the data `E` is bound to an instance of `Node<E>`. As for the NodeFactory idea, I am not sure I see how that helps, it's essentially moving the problem from one class to another, right?

Comment: As I said, you need to decide who knows how to create nodes. We can't decide for you, because we don't have the full picture of the problem. If the Node class knows how to build Node instances from data, then fine, make it a static method of Node. This is a classical factory method pattern.